# How access not accessible UI element?

Tags: windows, oracle-sqldeveloper, accessibility-insights

I am trying to automate SQL developer connection using FlaUI and windows accessibility insights tool but windows accessibility insights tool not detecting some UI element[plus[green button]].
[image: Please see image]

I am expecting that accessibility insights tool detect [plus_green_button] and return automation_id.

Comment: I believe that SQL Developer is written in Java - for automation see [this github issue](https://github.com/FlaUI/FlaUI/issues/127#issuecomment-354618987)

Answer (score 1):

When Accessibility Insights for Windows can see a window but not its individual elements, that usually indicates that you're attempting to scan an elevated process (eg, one you're launched with "Run as Administrator") from a non-elevated Accessibility Insights process. Try either running the application being scanned as a non-administrator or, if that is not possible, running Accessibility Insights for Windows using "Run as Administrator".

Comment: still it is not working, i opened both application in admin mode still same isssue.

Answer (score 0):

Accessibility Insights for Windows leverages [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32), so it can only inspect applications that are compliant with UI Automation. I found a few posts online stating that SQL Developer is written in Java, using the Swing library. The Swing library does not support UI Automation, meaning that almost no detail appears in Accessibility Insights for Windows. Windows Narrator and Windows Magnifier also rely on UIA, so SQL Developer will be similarly limited there.

You can confirm this by using Accessibility Insights for Windows to test SQL Developer. It should display an error message that the framework in use does not support UI Automation. You can learn more about the history of this rule at https://github.com/microsoft/axe-windows/issues/554.